# C++11. auto in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda, std

I have the next code (C++11):

```
...

ATTRIBUTE_PROBLEM getAttrWithCustomType(const std::string& attrName) {
   auto attr = std::find_if(
                attributes.cbegin(),
                attributes.cend(),
                [&attrName](const auto& pair) { return pair.first == attrName; }
  ...

}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> attributes;
```

Configuration in my CMake file:

```
set_target_properties(HlsParser PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
    )
```

gcc version: *gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516*

If this code written in the .hpp file I got the next error. And it's expected behavior, C++11 doesn't support generic lambda.

```
error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
                 [&attrName](const auto& pair) { return pair.first == attrName; }
```

*My question:*

**BUT If I put this code to the .cpp file I haven't error while compilation. Could someone explain me this behavior?**

*EDITED (07.07.2021)*

Example of the project: https://github.com/ValentinNikin/TempCMakeProject

Comment: Your .cpp file is not compiled. Re-run cmake to re-configure the project.

Comment: Hello @S.M. Sorry for the long answer. My .cpp file is compiled. I double checked. If you want, you can try to build test project by yourself https://github.com/ValentinNikin/TempCMakeProject

Comment: `CXX_STANDARD 11` is set for the executable but not for the library, so the library is not compiled with `-std=c++11`. Note it is *target* properties, not *project* properties.

Comment: Hm... Thank you @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can I determine the standard used to compile the library? Can I hardcode the standard for all project?

Comment: The default standard depends on the compiler version. AFAICT you cannot set this property globally on a project, but you can use more than one target in `set_target_properties`.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you